# webm video keeps resizing in Chrome during playback

Tags: google-chrome, video, converters, playback, webm

I converted a video to webm through Any Video Converter and it plays fine in Firefox.  However, in Chrome it constantly resizes itself during playback and I'm not sure why.

I previously used Miro converter, but that video wouldn't play in Firefox at all for some reason.  It would jump instantly to the end of the video when I pressed play.  When using my custom settings, it did the weird resizing thing in Chrome, but when I exported it again using the default settings, it played normally in Chrome, but still nothing in Firefox, so I switched to using Any Video Converter and now the resizing issue is back.  I didn't change anything in the settings.

**Here's the link:**
http://kimkellermedia.com/videoTest.html

I'm using the latest versions of both Firefox and Chrome by the way.

Comment: I've tried messing with the sizing for the conversion, but still got the same result.  It's just really weird that this is happening with two converters, but only shows up when I put it in a webpage.  IT plays fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I never quite figured out what was causing the rapid size change during playback, but this link recommended some converters I haven't tried yet.  http://www.my-html-codes.com/html5-video-converters

I used **Free WebM Encoder** http://webmsoft.com/free-webm-encoder.html and everything works fine now on all browsers.  So, if anyone else has seen this weird issue, use this converter I guess.

It would still be nice to know what caused everything in the first place, just in case it happens again, but at least everything is fine now!  By the way, I've taken down the videoTest link I provided in the original question since I don't need it anymore.